# Waiting for database rows to load using TableDependency and F#

Tags: f#, reactive-programming, mailboxprocessor

I've got an F# project that loads some files to an outside subsystem and then uses [Table Dependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency) to wait for some rows to be added to a table as a side effect.

Table Dependency is used in the type below to watch for the db changes.  It fires a custom event when a row is added/changed/whatever:

```ml
// just using this type for the RecordChangedEvent to marshal the id we want into something
type AccountLoaded() = 
    let mutable someId = ""

    // this property name matches the name of the table column (SomeId)
    member this.SomeId 
        with get () = someId
        and set (value) = someId <- value

// AccountLoadWatcher
type AccountLoadWatcher() = 
    let mutable _tableDependency = null
    let event = new Event<_>()

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = 
            _tableDependency.Stop()
            _tableDependency.Dispose()

    // custom event we can send when an account is loaded

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member this.AccountLoaded = event.Publish

    member private this.NotifyAccountLoaded(sender : RecordChangedEventArgs<AccountLoaded>) = 
        let accountLoaded = sender.Entity
        event.Trigger(accountLoaded.SomeId)

    member this.Watch() = 
        _tableDependency <- DbLib.getTableDependency "dbo" "AccountTable" 
                                null
        _tableDependency.OnChanged.Add(this.NotifyAccountLoaded)
        _tableDependency.Start()
```

What I want to do is take the above object and just wait for all the rows with ids I care about to be loaded. What I have so far is:

```
let waitForRows(csvFileRows) =
  let idsToWaitFor = parseUniqueIdsFromAllRows csvFileRows

  let mutable collected = Set.empty
  let isInSet id = Set.contains id idsToWaitFor
  let notDone = not <| (Set.difference idsToWaitFor collected = Set.empty)
  let accountLoadedHandler id = 
      collected <- collected.Add id
      printfn "Id loaded %s, waiting for %A\n" id (Set.difference idsToWaitFor collected)
  loadToSubsystem csvFileRows |> ignore

  // wait for all the watcher events; filtering each event object for ids we care about
     watcher.AccountLoaded
           |> Observable.takeWhile (fun _ -> notDone) 
           |> Observable.filter (fun e -> isInSet e) 
           |> Observable.subscribe accountLoadedHandler
           |> ignore

  doMoreWork()
```

but that just continues to doMoreWork without waiting for all the events i need above.

Do I need to use a task or async?  F# Agents?

Comment: What do you do in `accountLoadedHandler`?

Comment: updated with the accountLoadedHandler and helper functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are using `Observable.takeWhile` in your example, I'm assuming that you are using the [FSharp.Control.Reactive](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.Reactive/) wrapper to get access to the full range of reactive combinators.

Your approach has some good ideas, such as using `takeWhile` to wait until you collect all IDs, but the use of mutation is quite unfortunate - it might not even be safe to do this because of possible race conditions.

A nice alternative is to use one of the various `scan` function to collect a state as the events happen. You can use `Observable.scanInit` to start with an empty set and add all IDs; followed by `Observable.takeWhile` to keep accepting events until you have all the IDs you're waiting for. To actually wait (and block), you can use `Observable.wait`. Something like this:

```
let waitForRows(csvFileRows) =
  let idsToWaitFor = parseUniqueIdsFromAllRows csvFileRows

  let finalCollectedIDs = 
    watcher.AccountLoaded
    |> Observable.scanInit Set.empty (fun collected id -> Set.add id collected) 
    |> Observable.takeWhile (fun collected -> not (Set.isSubset idsToWaitFor co llected))
    |> Observable.wait

  printfn "Completed. Final collected IDs are: %A" finalCollectedIDs
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the insight on not using mutable as well